# Constructor declared as constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr

I try example from IBM knowledge center:
I run it in visual studio 2019 and it looks different: despite that constructor is `constexpr` I can initialize member based on constructor input parameter in `D3`. as well in constructor body I can assign a member for `D3`. Whats is a reason for such diff? Wh contructor is defined constexpr ?

```
struct BASE {
};
struct B2 {
  int i;
};

struct D1 : public BASE {
  //OK, the implicit default constructor of BASE is a constexpr constructor.
  constexpr D1() : BASE(), mem(55) { }
  
  //OK, the implicit copy constructor of BASE is a constexpr constructor.
  constexpr D1(const D1& d) : BASE(d), mem(55) { } 

  //OK, all reference types are literal types.
  constexpr D1(NL &n) : BASE(), mem(55) { }

  //The conversion operator is not constexpr.
  operator int() const { return 55; }      

private:    
  int mem;
};  

struct D3 : B2 {
  //error, D3 must not be a function try block.   
  constexpr D3(int) try : B2(), mem(55) { } catch(int) { }

  //error, illegal statement is in body.
  constexpr D3(char) : B2(), mem(55) { mem = 55; } 
  
  //error, initializer for mem is not a constant expression. 
  constexpr D3(double i) : B2(), mem(i) { }

  //error, implicit conversion is not constexpr. 
  constexpr D3(const D1 &d) : B2(), mem(d) { }                   

  //error, parameter NL is a non-literal type.
  constexpr D3(NL) : B2(), mem(55) { } 

private: 
  int mem;
};
```

Comment: The rules for `constexpr` evolve with each update to the C++ standard. *"Whats is a reason for such diff?"* - The reason is likely that the IBM knowledge center is outdated.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica what is the reason for constructor to be constexpr now?

Comment: To do constant initialization for stuff appearing in constant expressions. As always.

Comment: Half related: `constexpr D3(int) try : B2(), mem(55) { } catch(int) { }` will likely work in C++20

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, [here's one I find interesting](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ad0Bp6QuB33AmxMW). Notice the error? The template argument is `8`. It's computed from the constant expression `A{5}.inc().inc().inc()`. All the members are `constexpr`, but they certainly modify `this`. In a nutshell, `constexpr` is about stuff being computable by the compiler, they don't have to to be hardwired entirely by the programmer.